# Reading Data from a Physical Hard Drive

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, file-io, hard-drive

I am trying to develop a program that goes and finds 2 connected unformatted physical drives and read bytes. The program currently runs in the administrator mode since that's the only way I guess the program can see unformatted hard drives. I am using visual studio 2015 and it runs in windows 7 machine.

The problem is that it can only read multiples of 512 (512 is the sector size). Currently the unformatted hard drives are located in disk 2 and 3 slots (they are both SSDs). It first reads 512 bytes (works without an issue) and doesn't do any more reads if it's a formatted hard drive. If it's an unformatted hard drive it goes ahead and read more bytes. If it's hard drive A it then reads the next 1024 bytes and it works (read_amount = 1024). If it's hard drive B it then reads the next 1025 bytes and it doesn't work (read_amount = 0). I am not sure why it can't read a multiple of a 512/sector sizes. My understanding is that when you call "CreateFile()" function with dwFlagsAndAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, I should be able to read sizes that are not multiples of sector sizes (if you use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING then you can only read multiples of 512 and I am NOT using that flag). See my code below.

// Hard_Drive_Read.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

// This program assumes you have EXACTLY TWO unformatted hard drives connected to your computer.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if (argc != 3)
{
    cout << "Need to enter 2 arguments" << endl;
    exit(0);
}

int frames_to_process = atoi(argv[2]);

if (frames_to_process < 1)
{
    cout << "invalid argument 2" << endl;
    exit(0);
}



//HANDLE hDisk_A;
//HANDLE hDisk_B;



LPCTSTR dsksrc = L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive";
wchar_t dsk[512] = L"";


bool channel_A_found = false;
bool channel_B_found = false;
char frame_header_A[1024];
char frame_header_B[1025];



HANDLE hDisk;
char buff_read[512];
DWORD read_amount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{


    swprintf(dsk, 511, L"%s%d", dsksrc, i);

    hDisk = CreateFile(dsk, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("%s%d%s", "couldn't open the drive ", i, "\n");
        CloseHandle(hDisk);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s%d%s", "successfully open the drive ", i, "\n");

        BOOL read_success_1 = ReadFile(hDisk, buff_read, 512, &read_amount, NULL);
        cout << "read amount 1 - " << read_amount << endl;
        if ((read_success_1 == TRUE) && (read_amount == 512))
        {


            if ((buff_read[510] == (char)0x55) && (buff_read[511] == (char)0xAA))  //  test for a formatted drive; is there other identifiers?
            {
                cout << i << " is a formatted drive" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "Not a formatted drive, trying to find sync " << endl;


                ofstream writeBinary_Test;

                if (i == 2)
                {
                    writeBinary_Test.open("file_A_test.bin", ofstream::out | ofstream::binary);
                    ReadFile(hDisk, frame_header_A, 1024, &read_amount, NULL);
                    cout << "read amount " << read_amount << endl;
                    writeBinary_Test.write(frame_header_A, 1024);
                    writeBinary_Test.close();
                }

                else if(i == 3)
                {
                    writeBinary_Test.open("file_B_test.bin", ofstream::out | ofstream::binary);
                    ReadFile(hDisk, frame_header_B, 1025, &read_amount, NULL);
                    cout << "read amount " << read_amount << endl;
                    writeBinary_Test.write(frame_header_B, 1025);
                    writeBinary_Test.close();
                }



                LARGE_INTEGER distanceToMove;      
                SetFilePointerEx(hDisk, distanceToMove, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);



            }
        }

        else
        {

        }

    }

    if (channel_A_found && channel_B_found)
    {
        cout << "both drives found" << endl;
        break;
    }
}


if ((channel_A_found == false) || (channel_B_found == false))
{
    cout << "Couldn't Find Hard Drive A or Drive B or Both" << endl;
    cout << "Exiting the program" << endl;
    exit(0);
}


CloseHandle(hDisk);



return 0;
}
```

Eventually, I want to use SetFilePointerEx() to move around the hard drive and I the program has to work with and data size (not multiples of 512). Therefore, it's imperative I can read sizes that's not multiples of 512. Any ideas of how to fix this program? Am I using my flags properly?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `ReadFile` check `FO_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` flag in [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) and if it set check buffer size and offset to be multiple `DeviceObject->SectorSize`. when is `FO_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` flag set ? I/O subsystem set it when you use `FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` option in `CreateFile` *but* device itself can set it too. the `FileSystem\Raw` device (it mount the physical disk when you open it and handle your fileobject) always set this flag.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Volume handles can be opened as noncached at the discretion of the particular file system, even when the noncached option is not specified in CreateFile. You should assume that all Microsoft file systems open volume handles as noncached. The restrictions on noncached I/O for files also apply to volumes.

Although it doesn't spell it out explicitly, this applies to drives as well as to volumes.

In practice, this isn't a problem.  It is straightforward to write a helper function that returns an arbitrary amount of data from an arbitrary offset, while performing only aligned reads.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to write a helper function for SetFilePointerEx() as well. I would ideally want everything to behave how fseek() and fread() behaves. Couple of questions, 1) I don't quite understand the difference between a volume and disk. I assume volume is a logical form of the disk, is disk access faster than volume access?  2) I also read some people so better performance with fread compared to ReadFile(). As long as you enable cache with ReadFile() can it still be slower than fread?

Comment: `fread` is a C runtime library function that ultimately calls `ReadFile` to do the actual work.  Because it buffers the data in user-mode, it may perform better than `ReadFile` if you are doing lots of small reads.  The primary difference between a volume, e.g., `\\.\C:` and a drive `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` is that a drive represents an entire hard disk drive and a volume represents a single partition.  You're also talking to a different driver level so there may be some differences in the semantics, I don't recall the details off the top of my head.

Comment: You can of course implement your own `fread` and `fseek` equivalents.  If you're using Visual Studio you can even look at the C runtime library source code to see how Microsoft does it.

Answer (score 1):

> It's imperative I can read sizes that's not multiples of 512.

That is not possible. For direct access of a disk, you can only read and write multiples of the sector size. Furthermore, you must align your read and write operations. That is the file pointer must be at a multiple of the sector size.

If you want to present an interface that allows arbitrary seeking, reading and writing, then you will need to implement your own buffering on top of the aligned raw disk access.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx  
an application must meet certain requirements when working with files opened with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. The following specifics apply:
•File access sizes, including the optional file offset in the OVERLAPPED structure, if specified, must be for a number of bytes that is an integer multiple of the volume sector size. For example, if the sector size is 512 bytes, an application can request reads and writes of 512, 1,024, 1,536, or 2,048 bytes, but not of 335, 981, or 7,171 bytes. what if you use FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL?

Comment: Buffering is a higher level feature, that you get when working with volumes. When you access the disk directly, there is no buffering and you must use aligned access.

Comment: well I initially tried to convert the HANDLE to a file pointer using _open_osfhandle() function and _fdopen(). It was mostly working but then I realize that fseek() and fread() wasn't working always. For example, when I did a fseek that' not a multiple of 512 (positive), fread couldn't start reading inside a sector( it started always from the beginning of the sector). However, it worked fine if it had a negative offset. Then I decided to use this approach. Do you have any ideas of reading bytes that are NOT multiples of sector sizes from an unformatted hard drive? I appreciate your comments

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make my answer any more clear. I am sorry to be the bearer of bad news. But you are just going to have to accept the need for aligned access. If you need to present an interface that is not aligned, add your own buffering layer. I already said all of that in the answer. I've said it again now. I have nothing more to add.