# Read/Write to unformatted SD Card on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to read/write to an SD card that is unformatted and I am having issues. I am using the windows API to open a handle to the SD card and read/write to it, however I get various errors depending on my approach.
Below is me trying to access the SD card by volume label:

```
HANDLE sdCardHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\E:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if(sdCardHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
  return;
}

// I have also tried using VirtualAlloc() to get a sector aligned buffer
unit8_t buffer[512] = { 0 };
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

if(WriteFile(sdCardHandle, buffer, 512, &bytesWritten, NULL) != TRUE)
{
  DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
  CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
  return;
}
```

However the WriteFile fails and the last error is 87 which is invalid parameter. I have tried locking the volume and also unmounting the volume before writing also and it failed.

The next attempt was to try and write to the physical drive instead by running the following in administrator mode:

```
HANDLE sdCardHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

if(sdCardHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
  return;
}

// I have also tried using VirtualAlloc() to get a sector aligned buffer
unit8_t buffer[512] = { 0 };
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

if(WriteFile(sdCardHandle, buffer, 512, &bytesWritten, NULL) != TRUE)
{
  DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
  CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
  return;
}
```

Which also fails but return error 23 which is a bad CRC error. I have also tried unmounting and locking the volume first but nothing changed. If there is any thing else I need to do or try please let me know.

Comment: Can you actually buy unformatted SD cards?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes you can. Whenever I insert into my computer it displays the volume label but I can't access it since it's unformatted.

Comment: If it has a volume label, it must be formatted. The label is part of the formatting.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Sorry I misspoke. It's not a volume label but a drive letter like C:\

Comment: You appear to have a broken SD card. Not uncommon.

Comment: @NeilButterworth So the SD card is used to store log files from a device that doesn't use a files system and just writes to it a sector at a time. The device can write to it so it must be working.

Comment: @TallerProgrammer e.g. a CPAP - some of them use an SD card for log storage, and I've heard some stories where the SD card was only recognized by the operating system if the correct software was installed.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct

Comment: Don't test != TRUE. The function indicates failure by returning zero, and success by returning non zero. Simply treat the return value as a truth value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Data from a Physical Hard Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002621/reading-data-from-a-physical-hard-drive)

Comment: @NeilButterworth - *unformatted SD* - even unformated device allow read data -how we can determinate formated device or not without read data from it first ?

Comment: _return error 23 which is a bad CRC error_ In my experience, that _does_ indicate a faulty card.  The cheap ones on eBay (if it's one of those) are cr@p, I sent all mine back and bought a branded one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all of your help and suggestions. It turns out I was doing the operation correct the entire time. However the SD card reader was causing the error. The issue I believe is that BitDefender might not be allowing the read/write operations to go out to the physical disk. I instead used a USB adapter that shows the SD card as USB drive and my read/write works! Hopefully this helps anyone having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

from [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)

> Volume handles can be opened as noncached at the discretion of the
>   particular file system, even when the noncached option is not
>   specified in CreateFile. You should assume that all Microsoft file
>   systems open volume handles as noncached. The restrictions on
>   noncached I/O for files also apply to volumes.

so we need assume that `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` (`FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING`) will be used:

> [Specifying this flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntcreatefile) places the following restrictions on the caller's
>   parameters to other ZwXxxFile routines.
>
> - Any optional `ByteOffset` passed to `NtReadFile` or `NtWriteFile`    must be a multiple of the sector size.
> - The `Length` passed to `NtReadFile` or `NtWriteFile` must be an    integral of the sector size. Note that specifying a read operation to 
>     a buffer whose length is exactly the sector size might result in a
>     lesser number of significant bytes being transferred to that buffer
>     if the end of the file was reached during the transfer.
> - Buffers must be aligned in accordance with the alignment requirement    of the underlying device. To obtain this information,
>     call    `NtCreateFile` to get a handle for the file object that
>     represents    the physical device, and pass that handle to `NtQueryInformationFile`. For a list of the system's  FILE_XXX_ALIGNMENT values, see `DEVICE_OBJECT`.

note, that here - [*Alignment and File Access Requirements*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/file-buffering) was wrong information:

> File access buffer addresses for read and write operations should be
>   physical sector-aligned, which means aligned on addresses in memory
>   that are integer multiples of the volume's physical sector size.
>   Depending on the disk, this requirement may not be enforced.

this is false - buffer addresses for read and write operations must **not** be physical sector-aligned. it must be aligned in accordance with the alignment requirement of the underlying device. this is absolute different things. 
we can get this align from [`FILE_ALIGNMENT_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_file_alignment_info) (win 8+) or by using [`FILE_ALIGNMENT_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_alignment_information) via [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) with `FileAlignmentInformation`

in your current code you hardcode buffer size to 512. however sector size of device can be bigger size.

> // I have also tried using VirtualAlloc() to get a sector aligned
>   buffer

how i say - you **not** need sector aligned buffer (usual device align 2-4 bytes). but you need buffer integral of the sector size. so before read data - you need first query sector size and device align required

```
HANDLE sdCardHandle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

if (sdCardHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    FILE_ALIGNMENT_INFO fai;
    if (GetFileInformationByHandleEx(sdCardHandle, FileAlignmentInfo, &fai, sizeof(fai)))
    {
        ULONG BytesReturned;
        STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR saad;
        STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageAccessAlignmentProperty, PropertyStandardQuery }; 
        if (DeviceIoControl(sdCardHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), &saad, sizeof(saad), &BytesReturned, 0))
        {
            if (PBYTE pb = new BYTE[saad.BytesPerPhysicalSector + fai.AlignmentRequirement])
            {
                PBYTE buf = (PBYTE)(((ULONG_PTR)pb + fai.AlignmentRequirement) & ~(ULONG_PTR)fai.AlignmentRequirement);
                if (ReadFile(sdCardHandle, buf, saad.BytesPerPhysicalSector, &BytesReturned, 0))
                {
                    __nop();
                }
                else
                {
                    GetLastError();//RtlGetLastNtStatus();
                }
                delete [] pb;
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(sdCardHandle);
}
```

also as separate note - when you use `OPEN_EXISTING` - any file attributes is ignored (it used only when you create new file). as result use `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` - senseless (but not error - simply will be ignored)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I have learned something new about how the physical disk behaves. However the problem ended up being the physical SD card reader. I have posted my own answer.

Comment: @TallerProgrammer - i not think so. what is actual sector size on SD ?

Comment: When I read the disks geometry it reports 512 for the sector size.